# Invertibility of a Polynomial map.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

Given following polynomial map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to V\subset \mathbb{R}^3 $:
$$
(z_1,z_2)\mapsto (2z_1-z_2, 2z_1^2-z_2^2, 2z_1^3-z_2^3)
$$

Is this map a bijection? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your map is polynomial, it cannot be bijective from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ as it goes from dimension $2$ to dimension $3$.

In fact the image needs to be in a variety of dimension $\le 2$, which corresponds to say that the points of the image satisfy some polynomial equation.

In your case, you can easily check that $(0,0,1)$ is not in the image.

However, if you denote by $V$ the image, then yes it is bijective.

Indeed, write $(a,b,c)$ a point of the image, and working with the explicit description you cand eliminate $z_1,z_2$ in terms of the others. You find

$$z_1=\frac{a^3-c}{2(a^2-b)}, z_2=\frac{a^3-3ab+2c}{3b-3a^2}.$$
Moreover, the equation of the image is $a^6-3a^4b-8a^3c+9a^2b^2+12abc-9b^3-2c^2$.

Comment: It is certainly not a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $V$ be the Variety to which all the points $(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2 $ gets mapped to under this mapping. Then in that case does the inverse mapping for $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to V$ exist? If so, is it one to one?

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer by showing that it is bijective from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $V$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more question. In this case we could eliminate one of the variables and solve explicitly for $z_1$ and $z_2$. But, in general, how do we show that such an explicit inverse exists?

Comment: Dear Jérémy, this is a nice answer. But you probably overlooked the fact that the image by a polynomial map is in general constructible, not necessarily locally closed. In the present example, the points $(a,a^2,a^3)$ of the closed subset you defined might not all be in the image.

Comment: It is true that my answer only shows that the map is birational to its image and that some points are not defined under the map that I gave. However, we have $f(a,a)=(a,a^2,a^3)$, so it is bijective on this set. However, if you really want the map to be bijective, you need to see what happens on the points where $a^2=b$.